# Linking css and html files

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, stylesheet

I am at my wit's end trying to link my CSS stylesheet to my HTML file, any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

- they are in the same folder
- my ide of choice is notepad++ (if that makes a difference)
- the naming of each file is correct
- I have tried multiple browsers

my code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Christian Potts' Virtual Resume</title>
    <style>
     <link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "style.css" />

    </style> 
</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

stylesheet:

```
/* style.css */

h1 {
    color: Blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<style>` tags around your `<link>` tag.

The `<style>` tag is used to define style information for an HTML document as known as CSS.
Inside the `<style>` element you specify how HTML elements should render in a browser by writing CSS.

In a `<style>` your write pure CSS. You can't link your stylesheet inside a `<style>` tag.

You should end up with this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Christian Potts' Virtual Resume</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW welcome to StackOverflow. It is appreciated to accepted the answer which is working for you. Voting is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **<style>** tag which is wrapped around **<link>** tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag should be in the head tag, not the style tag

So it would be as followed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Christian Potts' Virtual Resume</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```